# -Wstringop-overflow compiler warning in custom fmt::formatter<std::bitset<N>> specialization

Tags: c++, g++, template-specialization, user-defined-types, fmt

I am trying to create a specialization of `fmt::formatter` for `std::bitset` class. However I'm getting an ambiguos warning message from GCC when compiling the below [program](https://godbolt.org/z/zo5Y63Ezb):

```
#include <bitset>
#include <cstddef>
#include <fmt/core.h>


template <std::size_t N>
struct fmt::formatter< std::bitset<N> > : fmt::formatter< const char* >
{
/*  constexpr auto parse( format_parse_context& ctx )
    {
        return ctx.begin( );
    }*/

    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format( const std::bitset<N>& value, FormatContext& ctx )
    {
        return fmt::format_to( ctx.out( ), "{}", value.to_string( ) );
    }
};


int main( )
{
    std::bitset<8> bitset1 { 0b01010101 };
    fmt::print( "bitset1: {}\n", bitset1 );
}
```

Part of the warning message:

```bash
warning: writing 1 byte into a region of size 0 [-Wstringop-overflow=]
```

How can I fix the issue (if there's actually one)?

Note: I have commented out the `parse` method and instead inherited from the `fmt::formatter<const char*>` specialization. This way I don't have to implement the `parse` method. It compiled without any warnings prior to inheriting from that specialization and commenting out `parse`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This warning is a known false positive in some versions of gcc. You can do any of the following to make it go away:

- Suppress the warning.
- Switch to a different version of gcc where the warning doesn't occur (see e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/YhdKv4vzM).
- Use the latest {fmt} from github.

Comment: So I don't need to be worried. Thanks.

Comment: One more question. I looked at the docs on your website to learn how to specialize the `fmt::formatter` for user-defined types and in your sample code snippets, you have included `<fmt/format.h>` in the first line. So I included `<fmt/format.h>` in my `Formatters.hpp` file (which is basically a collection of `fmt::formatter` specializations) and it increased the size of my small executable from 31.3 KB to 121 KB. Thus I decided to instead include `<fmt/core.h>` and the size got back to 31.3 and the program links and runs well. I have not seen any problems so far. But why?

Comment: I mean where is that huge size coming from? Is it because my linker doesn't know how to exclude the unused {fmt} code?

Comment: Normally there shouldn't be size differences in optimized mode.

Comment: I use the `-flto` option. I don't know why it generates so much more code.